# Pylab / matplotlib magic in IPython: supress loading message

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

Currently in `IPython`, when you call `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` the following message displays under the code block.

> "Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib"

How I can suppress this message from being displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a builtin way of suppressing that message since if you look at the %pylab magic function in [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py) file you can see that the print statement is hard coded in there.

If this is a one-off kind of thing you can simply comment/remove that print line from your local library. (Typically it would be found at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py`.) Or possibly redirect stdout to devnull or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, trying to automate things with ipython. I think I'll just file a bug and a pull request to add this feature.

Comment: The solution is to simple not use pylab, matplotlib actually doesn't produce the message.